# What does spikeline in a chart mean?

Tags: javascript, charts, line

We are developing a dashboard application with a lot of charts, using Highcharts Javascript library. And we are asked to draw some charts with spikeline. I am not sure what a spikeline in a chart is. Can someone shed some light?

Comment: Sounds like it's one of the business things like "Always choose your axis so that the line goes from bottom left to top right."  Googling seems to just yield that it's a chart with a spike in it somewhere... business people like spikes, they tend to indicate something good happened.

Comment: Why don't you ask the clients? Perhaps they mean "sparkline."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand the spike line reflects a line with highest values in a certain time span. On [this page](http://www.thegasgame.com/features/todays-fair-price/) it is used to determine when is the best time to buy gas. There are graphics on the aforementioned page that may help you further.

Comment: That's what I was thinking after googling, just wanted to make sure. I think they need talk to their sales department instead of developers about that. Thank you guys for your efforts.

Comment: Glad I could help. I agree on talking to their sales persons, but at the same time think a programmer has the liberty to ask for an explanation if it's non programmer terminology. It's wise to clarify what a client means, if you don't you can end up with software they won't use.

Comment: Yes I will do that because like Matt Ball said - "Perhaps they mean Sparkline."